# How do I apply for a visa for my elder sister to care for me after my surgery?

Tags: standard-visitor-visas, family

I am having abdomen surgery in September and I would need my sister to take care of me as my husband is working full time and will not be able to take too many days off.
My sister has her own house and comfortable income from shop rent in Pakistan, but has no proof like bank statements etc. as all the transactions flows by cash-in-hand.
My husband will sponsor this trip including all the maintenance.
Do we still need bank statement in this case?
She is a widow age 57

Comment: We do not know which country/region (EU, UK, USA?) do you target for travel, but it is extremely likely a duplicate question. Normally all visitors require bank statements to prove that they are financially stable, could afford the trip and do not intend to stay apart from sponsorship. So the answer will be almost always yes.

Comment: Taking care of somebody might be considered work (i.e. it is work that someone else would otherwise be paid for if it weren't your relative or friend), and therefore, it may not be possible for your sister to do this on a visitor visa.

Answer (score 6):

You don’t specifically state which country your sister wants to visit. Despite having a sponsor, your sister still needs to meet the eligibility requirements in her own right. She will need to provide financial information to help the ECO understand her personal circumstances in Pakistan. This extensive answer explains why in more detail, on the assumption that your sister wants to apply for a U.K. visa [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab)